# How do I loosen the fit of a T-ring to ease mounting/dismounting a telescope adapter?

Tags: canon, astrophotography, lens-adapter

I recently bought a reflecting telescope, and along with it a Canon EF T-Ring (and adapter tube) to complement my Canon T3i.  The fit is extremely tight, which not only makes it difficult to fully twist on, but also to twist off.  More importantly, I'm worried about metal shavings falling into the camera body and potentially damaging the main sensor or auto-focus sensor.

What can I do to make this adapter go on and off the camera body easier (that also won't potentially damage the camera, obviously)?  Should I take a file to the T-ring in order to remove any rough edges and increase the tolerances; should I be using graphite, grease, or oil as a lubricant; or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Try a rubber band wrench from an auto parts type store, or rubber gloves with your fingers and palm evenly spaced around ring. Don't squeeze too hard--just enough to make even contact. You can also put Anti-seize compound, from the same type of store, on your fingertip then onto the threads. Only coat the threads very lightly; it will spread around when attached.

Comment: The problem with a strap-wrench is that I want to avoid needing a tool each and every time I want to attach or remove the ring.